# Hiding modal when no data is received in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, codeigniter-3

```
<div class="modal fade"  id="popup" data-interval="false" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" id="">
          <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-body">
             <div class="">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="cut">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick= "closePopup() "><i style="color: #6f6e6e; font-size: 20px;" class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
                        </div>
                            <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <?php 

                                    if($popupsData!=''){
                                        $image=0; 

                                        foreach ($popupsData as $key => $row) { 
                                            if($row['type']=='Image'){
                                                if($image<3){ 
                                            ?>
                                    <!-- The slideshow -->
                                      <div class="carousel-item <?php echo $image==0?'active':''; ?>">
                                            <div class="img_pop">
                                            <img src="<?php echo UPLOADURL.'/popup/'.$row['image'] ?>">
                                            </div>
                                      </div>
                                    <?php } $image++; } } ?> 



                                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                                      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                                      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                                    </a>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

    <?php

       $actpop = print_r($popupsData);

    ?>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
          debugger;
         var modal_value = '<?php echo $actpop; ?>';
          if($('#popup').length>0 && modal_value!=''){
          debugger;
        $('#popup').modal('show') 
      }else{
         $('#popup').modal('hide') 
      }

    });



    </script>
```

What should be done to stop the popup modal, when no data is active in backend. I am receiving the pop-up blank when no data is active in backend.I am unable to do that. Please help me with the same.I am having this issue in codeigniter code hide the modal when no data is received in variable.

Comment: Have you tried changing the if condition to just check for `modal_value`

Comment: @ascsoftw you mean that I should do this : 
<?php 
  if($popupsData!=''){?>
 <div class="modal-body">

Comment: Try this. `if(modal_value!=''){`

Comment: Thank You @ascsoftw. I hid the whole div , using if($popupsData!=''){?>...It has worked.......Thank you.